# PHP pre_split looses first character

Tags: php, numbers, missing-data, preg-split

I have the following string, and want to split the name from the invoiceid. The name could have a space, and possibly a hyphen as well.

> $invoice_id ="May-Ann Jane-28188-1600086909";

```
    $invoice_id ="May-Ann Jane-28188-1600086909";
    
    $exploded = preg_split('/[-]+[0-9]/', $invoice_id,3 ); 

foreach($exploded as $index => $answer){ 
  if (!empty($answer)){ 
    echo $index.": ".$answer."<br />"; 
  } 
  
} 

$prefix = $exploded[0]; 
$invoiceid = $exploded[1]; 
$transid = $exploded[2]; 

echo '<BR>list2:<BR />';  
echo "prefix :".$prefix."<br />"; 
echo "invoiceid :".$invoiceid."<br />";
```

On the output, the first character of any number is lost:

```
0: May-Ann Jane
1: 8188
2: 600086909

list2:
prefix :May-Ann Jane
invoiceid :8188
transid :600086909
```

how do I get that first character back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split using a positive lookahead `(?=` asserting a digit on the right instead of matching it. That way you keep the digit.

```
-(?=[0-9])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4SaVYd/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/LGNfE)

```
$invoice_id ="May-Ann Jane-28188-1600086909";
$exploded = preg_split('/-(?=[0-9])/', $invoice_id, 3);
print_r($exploded);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => May-Ann Jane
    [1] => 28188
    [2] => 1600086909
)
```